# Spring Security Multiple HTTPSecurity with Different User Details Services Not Working in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have two types of users: Application User and End User and I have separate tables for these. Now, I want to apply security on these two tables.

I provided custom implementation of ***UserDetailsService*** for Application users:

```
@Component("applicationUserDetailsService")
public class ApplicationUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {}
```

And, I provided another second custom implementation of ***UserDetailsService*** for End users:

```
@Component("endUserDetailsService")
public class EndUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {}
```

Now, in the following code snippet, I have registered two endpoints for both type of users. I have injected both implementation of ***UserDetailsService*** and registered by `@Overide configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` method for both application and end user separately.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Import(SecurityProblemSupport.class)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

// Injected via Constructor Injection
private final EndUserDetailsService endUserDetailsService;

private final ApplicationUserDetailsService applicationUserDetailsService;

@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class ApplicationUserSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html")
            .antMatchers("/test/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)
            .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
            .and()
            .headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .disable()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .antMatcher("/api/customer/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/customer/authenticate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/customer/**")
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .apply(securityConfigurerAdapter());
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(endUserDetailsService);
    }
}

//no @Order defaults to last
@Configuration
public class EndUserSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html")
            .antMatchers("/test/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)
            .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
            .and()
            .headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .disable()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()                               
            .and()
            .apply(securityConfigurerAdapter());
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(applicationUserDetailsService);
    }
}

private JWTConfigurer securityConfigurerAdapter() {
    return new JWTConfigurer(tokenProvider);
}
}
```

And, I'm trying to authenticate the user like this:

```
//Injected via Constructor Injection
private final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder;

UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken =
        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginVM.getUsername(), loginVM.getPassword());
Authentication authentication = authenticationManagerBuilder.getObject().authenticate(authenticationToken);
```

When the above code snippet is executed, I get the Null Pointer Exception because `authenticationManagerBuilder.getObject()` returns NULL. And when I use just when implementation of ***UserDetailService*** with `@Component("userDetailsService")` and not set ***UserDetailService*** in security config like `auth.userDetailsService("...")`, it works fine but by that way I can't achieve authentication from multiple tables.

***What I want to Achieve:***
In simple words, I want spring security to authenticate user from two tables.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to achieve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52783807/spring-security-multiple-userdetailsservice
But couldn't find any way

Answer (score 5):

`requestMatchers()` is the call that you need as it allows you to isolate adapters by URL:

```
@Order(1)
@EnableWebSecurity
class EndUserConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/api/customer/**")
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("CUSTOMER")
                .and()
            .apply(yourJointConfigurations());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(endUserDetailsService);
    }
 }
```

Regarding calling the `AuthenticationManager` directly, it would be ideal if you could rely on the existing filter chain to do the work for you. For example, since you are stateless, HTTP Basic might be a better fit for you, which you could apply to both configurations, instead of trying to have a dedicated `/authenticate` endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for saving my day.