# Spring boot security JwtAuthentication and OAuth together

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, oauth

i was trying that jwtAuthentication works on all routes except one "/directory/auth" this one i need that works with oauth and return a jwt token but i cant get that both work together

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
            httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
            .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource());
            /// the route "/authenticate" is my jwtAuthentication and "/directory/auth" is my oauth         
            httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/authenticate",
                    "/directory/auth").permitAll().
                anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and().sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        // trying to set oauth on one route
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/directory/auth").authenticated().and()           
        .oauth2Login()
        .userInfoEndpoint()
        .oidcUserService(oidcUserService);

    //others filters
    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(decryptInterceptor, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    httpSecurity.addFilterAfter(encryptInterceptor, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: i put another endpoint https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49450556/multiple-user-details-services-for-different-endpoints